# Transferring unemployment benefit for spouse of EU citizen

Tags: eu-spouses, unemployment-benefits

I am an EU citizen, but my spouse is not.  We are both resident in one EU country and will be moving to another one because I got a new job there.

The work contract of my spouse has ended recently (for reasons unrelated to our move) and they have registered for unemployment benefits.

I believe that EU citizens can transfer unemployment benefits to another EU country for a limited time (3 months?)

Does this apply to *spouses* of EU citizens as well?

---

Additional info as requested:

- My spouse has residence rights only as "spouse of EU/EEE/Swiss citizen", not independently.
- I am a citizen of neither of these two countries. I am *not* from Croatia (in case this is relevant).

Comment: You may want to disclose which pair of countries, whether you are a citizen of either of them (rather than generically an EU citizen), and if your spouse has their own residence rights other than as your spouse.

Comment: @user16259 Thank you. I added some info but would like to keep some privacy. If you think there is value in disclosing more information, let me know.

Comment: Residence rights don't always include rights to unemployment benefits. In the UK many foreign residents (but not EU nationals) are classed as 'no recourse to public funds'. I'm not certain that it will help to disclose more information so please don't unless someone with more expertise comes along and requests it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the local branch of the employment service (a government agency). They said that only EU citizens can transfer unemployment rights, not their non-EU family.  EU citizens can do this by applying for an [U2 form](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/finding-job-abroad/transferring-unemployment-benefits/index_en.htm).

Unfortunately, I do not have a reference for this claim. I am simply relaying the information given to me by an official.  While it is very likely correct, I have seen officials make mistakes in similar cases.